# extracting source code of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I wanted to extract the source code of an external website (not on my domain) and then parse it to make it an application. I know how to do it using Jsoup library for JAVA, but I was not able to find any links on how to do it using Javascript or Jquery or any client side web programming language. 
Can someone guide me on which library should I use. Basically, I want to get the HTML source code of a webpage and then parse it to extract certain links under certain tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to do this with JavaScript alone because of [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). That prevents you from reading information from other domains.

What you would have to do is use a [serverside proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) to fetch the information. An Ajax call can call the proxy to fetch the page.

Comment: I am trying to experiment by creating a chrome extension which will just load some images from a webpage. So I wont be having a server!